# Angular Custom ControlValueAccessor can't handle array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a custom ControlValueAccessor that handles an array as it's value.

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-control',
  templateUrl: './custom-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-control.component.scss'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomControlComponent),
    multi: true,
  }]
})
export class CustomControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  disabled: boolean;

  @Input()
  value: string[] = [];

  constructor(
  ) { }


  addElement(text: string) {
    this.value.push(text);
    this.value = [].concat(this.value);
    this.emitValueChange();
  }

  removeElement(text: string) {
    this.value.splice(this.value.indexOf(text), 1);
    this.value = [].concat(this.value);
    this.emitValueChange();
  }

  emitValueChange(): void {
    this.onChange(this.value);
  }

  writeValue(obj: string[]): void {
    this.value = obj;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }


  onChange = (obj: any) => {
  };

  onTouched = () => {
  };
}
```

Then I have a custom validator to check if at least on element is present.

```
export class CustomValidators {
    static minSelected(min: number = 1): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
            if (control.value == null || !Array.isArray(control.value)) {
                // value is null or not an array
                return { minSelected: min, actualSelected: 0 };
            }
            else if (control.value.length < min) {
                // not enough
                return { minSelected: min, actualSelected: control.value.length };
            }
            else {
                // good to go
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I am using it like this in a FormGroup.

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  events: new FormControl([], [CustomValidators.minSelected(1)]),
});
```

The Problem is, that Angulars Forms do not detect changes in the value, after the initialization. I call the #addElement and #removeElement functions using buttons and inputs on the template. When I do console.log of the array, I can see all the changes. Also the DOM updates accordingly. But for some reason, the Validator is no longer called, when I change the value of the array. So illegal states (like no elements / empty array) are no longer picked up, and I can not validate the form properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot.

```
registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  this.onChange = fn;
}
registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  this.onChange = fn;
}
```

The sharp eye may notice, that I also bound the 'touched' handler to the change handler. I assume Angular has therefore overridden the 'change' handler, because it was bound before the 'touch' handler was.

Stupid mistake that cost me hours. Love it.